Azure Table Storage - how to fetch multiple records given multiple row keys all belonging to a single partition
I have a set of row keys say
CloudTable table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference("MyTable");
var partitionKey = "PK";
var rowKeys = new List<string>{"RK1","RK2","RK3"};

now if I want to get the records I could loop through the list and for each rk I could
var retrieve = TableOperation.Retrieve<MyRecordSchema>(partitionKey, rk);
var res = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieve);

but disadvantage is this doing multiple network calls to table storage and probably have higher cost + more time.
Is there some way to do this in 1 call since my partition key is the same the rows only need to retrieve from that partition. I'm using the package Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table

Yes you can, you do this by running a query with a filter like $PartitionKey = $pk and ( $RowKey = k1 or $RowKey = k2 or $rowKey = k3 [etc] ) - though Microsoft does discourage doing this: "Note that using an "or" to specify a filter based on RowKey values results in a partition scan and is not treated as a range query. Therefore, you should avoid queries that use...").

@Dai i see. so are you suggesting that doing multiple calls is the better way?

No, I'm just saying that there might be no good answer.

That said... how big are your partitions? If each partition has less than (say) 100 rows then it might be faster to just get the entire partition. Alternatively if you can somehow turn your RowKey predicates into a range query then that would give ou the best results  - so if you want 'RK1', 'RK2' and 'RK3' then your filter would be like $PartitionKey = pkValue AND $RowKey >= 'PK1' AND $RowKey <= 'PK3'.

@Dai querying the entire partition i think wont be practical for my case. however the list of row keys is actually sorted so can build a range. but withini that range it is possible to get a lot of unwanted records as well

Just filter-out the unwanted records as you read the results-in. ATS is full of hard-requirements for client-side processing of non-trivial queries - and many other inefficiencies like that (which I'm sure Microsoft is fine with as it all contributes towards your Azure billing!).

@Dai if you write an answer i will accept and close the quesion
